# How to show all console messages on a div?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have this code:

```
 if (typeof console  != "undefined")
          if (typeof console.log != 'undefined')
            console.olog = console.log;
          else
            console.olog = function() {};

        console.log = function(message) {
          console.olog(message);
          $('#debugDiv').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
        };
        console.error = console.debug = console.info =  console.log
```

Which works great for simple console logs, but i want everything there! all that the console in the browser shows me, i want in that div:

for example this:

```
  i170.png:1 GET http://localhost:3000/modules/core/img/items/i170.png 404 (Not Found)
    i183.png:1 GET http://localhost:3000/modules/core/img/items/i183.png 404 (Not Found)
```

is not shown in the div that i created, how can i make all of it shown there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a two questions here.

**1) dump all the arguments passed to console.log**

You get all the arguments of the function in [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). So here's a possible solution.

Change

```
console.log = function(message) {
      console.olog(message);
      $('#debugDiv').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
};
```

to

```
console.log = function() {
      console.olog.apply(console, arguments);
      $('#debugDiv').append('<p>' + [].map.call(arguments, JSON.stringify) + '</p>');
};
```

**2) get all errors**

The simplest solution is to add

```
window.onerror = console.log;
```

but note that some errors don't trigger `onerror` and can't be catched in JS.

Comment: Hmm, I may be mistaken but I'm pretty sure the error OP is wanting to catch is a browser-specific error and not one which will be exposed to the JavaScript code.

Comment: window.onerror = console.log where do add that one?

Comment: @totothegreat just after having replaced console.log with your function

Comment: instead of console.error = console.debug = console.info =  console.log?